# Appending numpy arrays using numpy.insert

Tags: numpy, insert

I have a numpy array (inputs) of shape (30,1). I want to insert 31st value (eg. `x = 2`). Trying to use the np.insert function but it is giving me *out of bounds error*.

```
np.insert(inputs,b+1,x)
```

> IndexError: index 31 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: you need to insert it at index `b`, not `b+1`.

The index you pass to [**`np.insert(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html), is the one where the element should be added. If you insert it at index `30`, then it will be positioned last. Note that indexes are zero-based. So if you have an array with 30 elements, then the last index is `29`. If you thus insert this at index `30`, we get:

```
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29])
>>> np.insert(a,30,42)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 42])
```

Comment: Thanks the error is gone, but when i print the array inputs, its not showing the appended value, only showing 30 values. 31st value is missing. The numpy array was earlier reshaped  using reshape(-1,1)

Comment: @Atul: it does not *modify* the array, it constructs a *new* array. Therefore it is often not a good idea to perform such inserts a lot, since you each time make a new object.

Comment: ok so whats the right way of adding values to an array of size (30,1) ? is  it using append ? Can you please provide the syntax.

Comment: @Atul: no usually one does not do much "appending", etc. You work with lists for example that you load in numpy arrays. Numpy is not meant to do calculations on individual elements, it is meant to do calculations "in bulk". For a small number of elements, numpy will be slower than vanilla Python. Numpy is thus meant to process huge amounts of data.

Comment: WHat can also help in this case is if i can get rid of first value at index 0 and add new value at the end thereby maintaining the size

Comment: @Atul: but even getting/setting elements at a specific index is not efficient in numpy. Numpy is in essence a library that communicates with an underlying C++ library. So that means every call you make is wrapped to that library. So in fact each call is "slow" so to speak. It only works very well if one such single call, can do a huge amount of work (for example calculating the sum of two 100x100 arrays), and thus boosting by the work that is done in the call.

Comment: ok so let me give more details about my problem. I have an array (inputs) with size (30,1). after running some computations on inputs, i get a value lets say x=2. Now i want to add x at the end in inputs and use only the last 30 values, again run computations , again add etc...Want to do this for many times. How can i achieve this ?